# How to show mdb(access) file fields(Include utf8(arabic persian) charactrers) with php?

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access, utf-8

I have an access(.mdb) file include Arabic or Persian characters.

and I need to use from it in php or import it to MySQL.

but it shows ???? instead of utf8 word.

this is my code:

```
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
$db_connstr = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=".realpath("test.mdb")." ; DefaultDir=".realpath("");
$conn->open($db_connstr);
$conn2 = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
//mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$rs = $conn->Execute("SELECT name FROM test");
while (!$rs->EOF)
{
    $name = $rs->Fields("name");
    //echo utf8_encode ( $name );
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (id,name) VALUES (NULL,'".$name."') ");
    $rs->MoveNext();
} 
$rs->Close();
```

then i use from `mysql_query("set names 'utf8'")` and `utf8_encode ( $name )`
but not work!

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your arabic characters are stored in CP-1256 in MS Access. You need to convert them to utf8 before writing into the database. I used PDO instead of your deprecated mysql_* functions. Put your username, password and db name:

```
<?php
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
$db_connstr = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=".realpath("test.mdb")." ; DefaultDir=".realpath("");
$conn->open($db_connstr);

try {
    //connect to mysql
    $username = 'user';
    $password = 'secret';
    $db_name = 'test';
    $mysql_conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$db_name, $username, $password);
    $mysql_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $mysql_conn->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    //prepare MySQL insert statement
    $stmt = $mysql_conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `test` SET value=:value');

    $rs = $conn->Execute("SELECT name FROM test");
    while (!$rs->EOF)
    {
        $name = $rs->Fields("name");
        //convert from cp1256 to uft8
        $name = iconv('cp1256', 'utf-8', $name);
        //insert into MySQL
        $stmt->execute(array("value" => $name));
        $rs->MoveNext();
    }
    $rs->Close();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: In this case print $name; and exit; after $name = $rs->Fields("name"); when launching the php script, redirect it's output into a file. Check the string encoding in the file.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay.
I try it and use from fwrite function. it is ANSI.

Comment: @user59 What kind of ANSI? cp1256 - is typical for Arabic.

Comment: How do I find out kind of ANSI?

Comment: Notepad++ > Encoding shows ANSI. It doesn't show the kind of ANSI.

Comment: @user59 In this case open this file in firefox and look at the encodings in View -> Character Encoding -> Middle Eastern. Set the correct one, so your text is shown, let me know, what it is.

Comment: It is Western(Windows-1252).

Comment: @user59 weird, how could Arabic characters be encoded in Windows-1252? Use $name = iconv('cp1252', 'utf-8', $name); in my answer instead of cp1256.